# Why my angular app create socket connection every time when it send post request?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient

I am building an Angular application for android or iOS devices, the app uses httpClient module to communicate with a Node js server. The app send post request periodically, I expect the app create a socket with server and continue use this socket for communication until user stop the app, but every time when app send the request, the created socket will close and a new one will be created again.

App uses below code to send data

```
...
this.http.post(this.url, body, { responseType: 'text' });
...
```

Node JS Server code is

```
var existSocket
server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

    console.log("Socket Connected, %s sockets now", sockets.length)
    console.log("%s (%s: %s)", socket.deviceId, socket.remoteAddress,
        socket.remotePort)
    socket.write('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' + 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080\r\n' + '\r\n')

    // handle socket events
    socket.on("connection", function () {
        console.log("Socket Connection Event")
        console.log("%s (%s: %s)", socket.deviceId, socket.remoteAddress,
            socket.remotePort)
    })

    socket.on("connect", function () {
        console.log("Socket Connect Event")
        console.log("%s (%s: %s)", socket.deviceId, socket.remoteAddress,
            socket.remotePort)
    })


    socket.on("close", function () {
        console.log("Socket Close Event")
        console.log("%s (%s: %s)", socket.deviceId, socket.remoteAddress,
            socket.remotePort)
        socketRemove(socket)
    })


    // handle socket device messages
    socket.on("data", function (data) { 
        if (existSocket == socket) {
              console.log(`closing socket for device: ${socketForDevice[socket.deviceId].remoteAddress}:${socketForDevice[socket.deviceId].remotePort}`)
              socket.destroy()
        }

        console.log(`setting socket for device: ${socket.remoteAddress}:${socket.remotePort}`)
        existSocket = socket

        socket.write('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n' + 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080\r\n' + '\r\n')                                 
    })
})
```

The log in server side shows:

```
Socket Connected, 1 sockets now
null (::ffff:101.187.107.123: 42646)

...

setting socket for device: ::ffff:101.187.107.123:42646

Socket Connected, 2 sockets now
null (::ffff:101.187.107.123: 42648)

...

closing socket for device: ::ffff:101.187.107.123:42646
setting socket for device: ::ffff:101.187.107.123:42648
```

It seems the problem is caused by the app sending different port number every time. How to make the app to send the same port number once app starting?

Comment: show your node js server setup code

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers have updated my question